# Get direct hierarchy in SQL without siblings of searched id

Tags: sql, select, ssms, recursive-query

I have a pretty simple table called Types which contians ID, ParentID and Name. What I need is to get the full hierarchy from an ID, but without including the siblings of the searched ID. I have written the following SQL,

```
;WITH cte AS ( 
   SELECT ID, ParentID, [Name]
   FROM   [Types]
   WHERE  ID=246
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT t1.ID, t1.ParentID, t1.[Name]
   FROM   [Types] t1 
   INNER JOIN cte ON cte.ID=t1.ParentID 
    ) 
SELECT * FROM cte
```

which gives me the full hierarchy of the table (with the topmost parent being id '246'):

[image]

So far, so good. What I would like now to get from the query is the full hierarchy of ID: 1384, but without the siblings of ID 1384 (and the siblings' children, grandchildren etc.). So it should return the following result:

```
+------+----------+------------------+
| ID   | ParentID | Name             |
+------+----------+------------------+
| 246  | 2        | Approvals        |
+------+----------+------------------+
| 1384 | 246      | ProductStatus    |
+------+----------+------------------+
| 1517 | 1384     | NewStatus        |
+------+----------+------------------+
| 1520 | 1384     | NewSiblingStatus |
+------+----------+------------------+
| 1519 | 1517     | NewNewStatus     |
+------+----------+------------------+
```

I've read various articles on retrieving hierarchies, but so far haven't come any closer to solving this problem or found someone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use two recursive common table expressions. One to get the parents, the other to get the children. You can then `union` them to get the result that you want - `union` (rather than `union all`) is on purpose to eliminate the duplicate on the initial node.

```
WITH 
    cte_children AS ( 
       SELECT ID, ParentID, [Name], 0 lvl
       FROM [Types]
       WHERE ID = 1384
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT t.ID, t.ParentID, t.[Name], lvl - 1
       FROM [Types] t
       INNER JOIN cte_children c ON c.ID = t.ParentID 
    ) 
    cte_parents AS ( 
       SELECT ID, ParentID, [Name], 0 lvl
       FROM [Types]
       WHERE  ID = 1384
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT t.ID, t.ParentID, t.[Name], lvl + 1
       FROM [Types] t
       INNER JOIN cte ON cte.ParentID = t.ID 
    ) 
SELECT * FROM cte_parents
UNION
SELECT * FROM cte_children  
ORDER BY lvl
```

Note that I added a column called `lvl` to the query, that computes the depth of each node (the intiial note has `0`, parents have negative `lvl`s, and children have positive `lvl`s) - this is handy to sort the final resultset.

Comment: Thank you very much! That gave me the result I was looking for.